# Hide access-control-allow-origin error from browser

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

I know **CORS,jsonp,proxy** can be used to do cross domain ajax call.Since I am **ignoring the return results**.I have used jquery post.

```
$.post("http://11.111.111.11/folder/filename.php",{reqid:rid} );
```

The data get posted and is working fine.But Browser shows cross domain request error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://11.111.111.11/folder/filename.php`. Origin `http://11.111.111.11` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there any way to hide this particular error only.